# Lediglich oder nur?

Tags: difference

As non-native German, I find difficult to perceive the difference between "nur" and "lediglich". In class it was told they are the same (typical reply to similar questions) but it looks like natives use them in different contexts.

What is the difference between "nur" and "lediglich" and how should I choose them?

Comment: Most speaker/writer use in a single sentence just one of them, not both at the same time, so how, in which context, did you experience different choices, which didn't look arbitrarly? Have you used a dictionary to find your suspicion confirmed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: *nur* has a wide ranges of usages, and *lediglich* is a synonym for only some of them.

Long story: First of all, there is the [particle *nur*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nur_denn_doch) which is used to emphasize a phrase in a certain way (difficult to explain in detail). You cannot use *lediglich* as a synonym for the particle *nur*.

Then there is the [adverb *nur*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nur_blosz_aber_ausnahmslos), which itself has several slightly different meanings. The Duden groups its examples (see the link, I don't want to quote the whole page here) by limitation (1), exclusiveness (2) and contradiction (3). The [adverb *lediglich*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lediglich) always expresses a limitation, it makes something "smaller", so it can replace *nur* in most of the examples in group (1), and since exclusiveness can be also seen as a kind of limitation you might hear phrases like in group (2) with *lediglich*, though I would not advise it - it feels a little bit wrong.

Let's have a closer look at the [Duden's examples](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nur_blosz_aber_ausnahmslos#Bedeutung1a) in group (1):

> das war nur ein Versehen
>       ich bin auch nur ein Mensch
>       ich bin nicht krank, nur müde
>       ich wollte nur sagen, dass

You can use *lediglich* instead of *nur* in the 1st and 4th phrase. It would also work in the 3rd phrase, but sound unidiomatic - "nicht / nur" is a fixed pair for expressing a contrast. In the 2nd phrase, *nur* is bound to *auch*. It means "I am just a man like everybody else". Replacing only *nur* with *lediglich* would sound strange, and replacing *auch nur* would change the meaning: "Ich bin lediglich ein Mensch" would lack the reference "like everyone else" and instead emphasize that I as a man have limited or unsufficient capabilities.

Looking at

> ich habe nur 10 Euro = I only have 10 Euro
>       ich habe nur noch 10 Euro = I only have 10 Euro left
>       sie sind nur mäßig begabt

you can use *lediglich* in the 1st and 3rd phrase without changing the meaning. It would sound a bit uncommon in the 2nd one and shift the emphasis from *left* to *only*.

So to come up with an ad-hoc rule of thumb: *lediglich* works as a synonym for *nur* when it expresses that something is small or limited and does not go along with some other adverb or particle (like "auch nur", "nur noch", "nicht / nur").

Last but not least, *nur* is a very common and frequently used word, whereas *lediglich* is a bit more elevated in style.

Comment: Somehow, it seems to me each *nur* in your examples could be replaced with *lediglich*, and the only reason why it sounds *a little bit* unusual in the "Ich bin auch nur ein Mensch." one is because we are dealing with a somewhat set phrase there.

Answer (score 5):

*Nur* and *lediglich* are adverbs with the same meaning. However, *nur* can be used a bit more broadly.

You can interchange the two words when you want to convey that something is restricted to what is being said.

> Ich habe doch nur[=lediglich] gesagt, ...
>   Er hat nur[=lediglich] seine Aufgabe erledigt.
>   Es dient nur[=lediglich] zur Information.

In the sense of *however* as a conjunction, you can't replace *nur*. But once you use *nur* as a plain adverb, it's fine again. Duden gives the following example:

> Die Wohnung ist hübsch, nur ist sie zu klein für uns.

Don't replace *nur* with *lediglich*, unless you make a small but signficant change to the sentence.

> Die Wohnung ist hübsch. Sie ist nur zu klein für uns.
>   Die Wohnung ist hübsch. Sie ist lediglich zu klein für uns.

Finally, *nur* is also a particle. Never interchange the two words here. Some examples taken from Duden:

> Nur mit der Ruhe!
>   Nur zu.
>   Iss nur.
>   Was hat er nur?
>   Wenn er nur käme.
>   Sie schlug die Tür zu, dass es nur so knallte.

Answer (score 1):

*nur* and *lediglich* can be used synonymously in some cases - when nur is used as an adjective or adverb. You can not replace *nur* with *lediglich* when nur is used as a particle. Compare the translations for *nur* and *lediglich* on dict.cc:

**nur**
only, merely, just, solely, but, exclusively, barely, none but, nothing but, as little as, no better than, no more than, as few as

**lediglich**
merely, solely, only, simply, entirely, but, just, no better than, as few as